# How do I horizontally align two columns in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, text-align

This is the HTML code for my BootStrap website:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Yanni Pang</title><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"><!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><!-- Animate CSS -->
    <link href="/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/minimalpace.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="plugins/pace.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    <link href="css/minimalpace.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Analytics -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
     (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
     })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

     ga('create', 'UA-17399906-5', 'auto');
     ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script><!-- End -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse animated fadeIn">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span></button> <a class="navbar-brand animated slideInLeft" href="/index.html">Yanni Pang</a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="disabled"><a href="/photos">Photos</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/articles">Articles</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/contact">Contact Me</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!-- <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                    <li class="navbarpills"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                    <li class="disabled"><a href="/photos">Photos</a></li>

                    <li><a href="/articles">Articles</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">test1</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#">test2</a></li>
                </ul> -->
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotronothercolor animated fadeIn">
            <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>

            <p class="lead">On this site, I will post random stuff!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="row marketing">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Education</h4>

                <p>I am a 9th grade High School student at RMHS. I am teaching myself how to program, and build things.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Missions Trips</h4><!-- <ul class="missionslist"> -->

                <ul class="missionslist">
                    <li style="list-style: none; display: inline">
                        <h5>Grace Chapel</h5>
                    </li>

                    <li>Trinidad 2014</li>

                    <li><a class="animated bounceIn" href="/navajonation">Navajo Nation 2015</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Sports</h4>

                <p>I swim competitively for the Reading Rockets Men's Swim Team. I have earned my varsity letter. Here are my records:</p><br>

                <p>50 Free: 26.75</p>

                <p>100 Breast: 1:17.93</p>

                <p>100 Free: 1:01:01</p>

                <p>Breath Holding Personal Best: 1:30:57</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h4>Hobbies</h4>

                <p>Swimming</p>

                <p>Coding</p>

                <p>Making</p>

                <p>Photography</p>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 tempspace">
                    <h4>Coding Experience</h4>

                    <p>HTML</p>

                    <p>CSS</p>

                    <p>Some Java</p>

                    <p>Some AppleScript</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h4>Photography Gear</h4>

                    <p>Canon EOS Rebel t6s</p>

                    <p>Video Ball Mount Tripod</p>

                    <p>Canon EF-S 18-135 Lens with Lens Hood</p>

                    <p>Canon EF 50mm STM</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 social animated fadeIn">
                    <a href="http://github.com/yannip1234"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> </span></a> <a href="http://youtube.com/yannip1234"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> </span></a> <a href="http://twitter.com/yannip1234"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg"> </span></a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <footer class="footer">
                <p>&copy; Yanni Pang 2014</p><img src="http://iplogger.org/1sF94.jpg">
            </footer>
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Space out content a bit */
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
.jumbotronothercolor {
    background: rgba(120,  163,rgba(210, 210, 210, 1)92, 0.79);
}
: : selection {
    background: #74ff7d;
}

/* Everything but the jumbotron gets side spacing for mobile first views */
.header,.marketing,.footer,.singlepage {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
/* MoreSpace for text */
.morespace {
    padding-left: 80px;
}
.lessspace {
    padding-left: 149px;
}
/* Nav Pills */
.nav-pills>li>a {
    color: #76a25b;
}
/* End Nav Pills */
/* Text Centered */
.col-lg-12 > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.col-lg-12 {
    text-align: center;
}
.col-lg-12 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff9a00;
    transition: .5s;
}
.col-lg-12 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #76a25b;
    transition: .5s;
}
/* Main Body Links */
.col-lg-6 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #76a25b;
    transition: .5s;
}

.col-lg-6 a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff9a00;
}
.col-lg-6 {
    text-align: center;
}
/* Main Body Links End */
/* Custom page header */
.header {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

/* Make the masthead heading the same height as the navigation */
.header h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}


/* Custom page footer */
.footer {
    padding-top: 19px;
    color: #777;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Customize container */
@media (min-width:  768px) {
    .container {
        max-width: 730px;
    }
}

.container-narrow > hr {
    margin: 30px 0;
}

/* Main marketing message and sign up button */
.jumbotron {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    color: #000;
}

/* Supporting marketing content */
.marketing {
    margin: 40px 0;
}

.marketing p + h4 {
    margin-top: 28px;
}

/* Responsive:  Portrait tablets and up */
@media screen and (min-width:  768px) {
    /* Remove the padding we set earlier */
    .header,.marketing,.footer {
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    /* Space out the masthead */
    .header {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    /* Remove the bottom border on the jumbotron for visual effect */
    .jumbotron {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
}
.tempspace {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.missionslist {
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.missionslist h4 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*Navbar*/
.navbar {
    border-radius: 0; 
}
.navbar-brand {
    font-size: 180%;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #74ff7d;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #ff9a00;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
    color: white;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  border: none;
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
.navbar-toggle .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 10%;
}
.navbar-toggle .middle-bar {
  opacity: 0;
}
.navbar-toggle .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: 10% 90%;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .top-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .middle-bar {
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle.collapsed .bottom-bar {
  transform: rotate(0);
}
/*End*/
/*NavajoNation*/
.singlepage {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
}

.navajonation {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: auto;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.navajonationdonate {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.navajocenter {
    text-align: center;
}

/*NavajoNation End*/

/*Col Center*/
.row-centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
/* reset the text-align */
    text-align: left;
/* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right: -4px;
}

/*Col Center End*/
.tab {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

/* Classes */
.pull-left {
    float: left!important;
}

.pull-right {
    float: right!important;
}

// Usage as mixins
.element {
}

.another-element {
}
.watermark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent url(http://yannipang.com/images/watermark.png) bottom right no-repeat;
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

This is how it appears:

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlOhU.png)

How do I align 'Photography Gear' and 'Coding Experience' horizontally so they are parallel like the others? Also why is there a big space between the bottom of 'Sports' and 'Photography Gear'?This has been bugging me for a while now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Share only relevant code. We can't lost time reading all your code and imaginating where is the problem. Another good point is that you share code on a fiddle, not linked the real website, there are many people that can't browse over several pages

Answer (score 0):

You forgot close the div - second row (with sports and hobbies).

Answer (score 0):

The second row div is not closed before starting the next row which causes them to be nested.

```
    ...
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <h4>Hobbies</h4>
        <p>Swimming</p>
        <p>Coding</p>
        <p>Making</p>
        <p>Photography</p>
    </div>
</div> <!-- This row closing tag is missing -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 tempspace">
        <h4>Coding Experience</h4>
        <p>HTML</p>
        <p>CSS</p>
        <p>Some Java</p>
        <p>Some AppleScript</p>
    </div>
    ...
```

Then you also have a stray closing div tag at the bottom before the closing body tag.  You probably threw it down there by accident to fix a tag warning.